# Unknown class in MXML file

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, mxml

I am taking over a Flex / MXML project for work. The last programmer lost the original source code so I ran it through a decompiler. In the main MXML file there are 3 lines that return errors.

IMPORT COM.TURBO.*

I've never heard of this and I can't seem to find anything on it. I assume its some kind of plug-in. Does anyone know what it is?

Comment: have you tried compiling it without those import statements?

Comment: There are possibly undefined methods errors, which are actually classes and variables that i think are related to the com.turbo.*

Comment: LoginManager, LoginSingleton, UserDAO are the classes

Comment: Maybe the decompiler lost something but that doesn't usually happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every developper can define his own package, insert in the packages some mxml or as classes and import the class everywhere into code. Normally, the packagenames should be unique and a inoffical rule says, named your package with your own url prefix (com.mycompany.MyOwnClassInMXML)
It can be a simple helperclass for whatever, convert 5 numbers in a array.

There are many decompiler with different power. so try another or try to find out, what he did with this class.

I have no knowledge, how complex your project is. Is the class with the error an mxml? If yes, at the top, you should find a namespace like

```
xmlns:whatever="com.turbo.*"
```

As a result, everywhere in your code, some components start with  instead of  or . Try to find out for what purpose the component with own prefix is and comment it out, if possible.

BR
Frank